# Raspberry as dialin-server

Tags: networking, gsm, ppp

Want use raspberry in a place where isn't any WiFi, but got GSM coverage.

Need connect to the device - e.g. looking for a sort of GSM modem solution what will works as classic old-style modem-based inbound connections, e.g.

- in my PC i will use GSM modem to call
- and the raspberry will listen for the ring and starts "ppp" or "slip".

So, the question is

- it is possible?
- what type of HW i should to use - e.g. exists some GSM modem what allows inbound conncetions?
- the SW solution is probably something like here:

  - https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_dialin_server or
  - http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Modem-HOWTO-12.html

*In short: how to connect **to** the raspberry where isn't any Internet?* (some good guide with some exact solutions would be the best :)

Comment: Does your GSM provider still provide [CSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_Switched_Data#Availability) or HSCSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all modems can be used for dial in. Almost all landline modems will work fine for dial in, but with GSM modems you need to verify that it will work. The fast easy way to check is to verify that it will sind RING messages and supports the ATA. If the modem meets those requirements it will work (with suitable adaptors). Install mgetty and read its documentation for software details. If the modem does not support those features there is still a slim chance it will work, but it will be much harder to setup. The modem bobstro linked to may work, but it is designed for other use cases (it is designed for continuous internet connection) and probably will not work with mgetty. Unfortunately you will probably need to talk to a salesman to find the right modem for your use case. If this is noncommercial you may also want to look at HAM based radio modems.

P.S. use ppp not slip. slip is better than nothing, but ppp is much easier to use.

Comment: a quick search for suitable modems found http://www.moxa.com/product/OnCell_G2111.htm , http://www.ebay.com/itm/GSM-Modem-for-Wavecom-Q2303A-Module-AT-Commands-RS232-New-/121539009486 and http://www.westermo.com/web/web_en_idc_com.nsf/alldocuments/7DBA46A89F3016B7C12578930034549E which if you can find manuals for all look line posible canidents. I only looked at each one for a couple seconds.

Comment: also many cell phones have modems built in, if you can find the right cable.

Answer (score 0):

Since Raspbian is based on Debian, if you buy a USB 56k modem and connect it to the Pi, you would probably be able to make the Pi listen for calls. I'm not sure how to do this exactly though, but it might help if you search Google for "Setup Debian as dialup server". It's most likely possible.

Comment: That would connect an analog modem. What about connecting to the GSM network?

Comment: He's connecting from the PC, which is dialing the Pi, so if the Pi is on a landline the PC will call over GSM to the landline, so in theory this method should work since the Pi is the one answering.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now that I re-read the question. @jm666 - to confirm: You're using a POTS telephone line at the RPi end?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy [GSM modems](http://www.getwirelessllc.com/products/sierra-wireless-airlink/raven-xt?gclid=Cj0KEQjwiN6sBRDK2vOO_vaRs5cBEiQAfsnJCQxm5rB_ay_Rz2Bby6A0QDzYNsogM2Pc4oMbkqwXYm4aAhvA8P8HAQ) but the modem itself is expensive, and you're going to need some sort of data plan for it. You can get models that connect via USB, or Ethernet.